# *ngIf with conditional &&

Tags: angular6

trying to give *ngIf condition for button, seems I am unable to achieve this below is the code.
I am able to show button if I give one conditions but I need to show button on both conditions

```
<button title="Review" 
*ngIf="pimr.Status === 'success' && pimr.Status === 'failed'" 
class="btn btn-icon" (click)="onAdd()">
<clr-icon shape="eye"></clr-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: you should use the || operator to achieve this and not && operator

Comment: Thanks, my mistake..

Answer (score 0):

- Since u want to show the buttons on both the conditions , you can use "||" Operator.
- So that the button can be displayed on either 'success' or 'failed' status.